# Copy from One Workbook in Excel to Another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am ultimately going for something more complex, but I can't even get this simple version to work.

It will open the other files, but it just leaves the 2nd workbook (the one with the macro that stuff is supposed to be copied to) blank.

I have tried some suggestions from other "copy/paste between workbooks" threads and nothing is working.

Most give me a "paste method of worksheet class failed" error which I have no clue how to fix as even PasteSpecial doesn't fix it?

I am relatively new to VBA and need to get something running for my job.  Thanks in advance for any help!

In my sample code below, I'm trying to copy from CPWholeDocTest1.xlsx to CPWholeDocTest2.xlsm.

```
Sub CopyPasteRawData()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rnewma\Documents\Excel Projects\Test\CPWholeDocTest1.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rnewma\Documents\Excel Projects\Test\CPWholeDocTest2.xlsm")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:B5").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")

'Close x:
'x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running this code from a macro enabled workbook or are you trying to run it from the .xlsx file ?

Comment: From the xlsm file, so it should be Macro Enabled.

Comment: Did you test R3uK's answer below, because I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Yes I did.  It comes up completely blank.  I even copy/pasted his modification over mine just to make sure I wasn't missing anything else and I just get nothing.

Comment: It might be a problem with re-opening your workbook if it's already open.

Comment: If you are running the code inside your .xlsm workbook, change Set y = Workbooks.Open(".....") to set y = ThisWorkbook.
Did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick!  Now to begin work on the much more complex version that will yank a varying number of lines (which thankfully starts in A3 everytime and the end will be the bottom line minus 1) to the other workbook.

Answer (score 0):

When transferring data from one range to another, you must add `.Value` or `.Value2` to be explicit!

 (`.Value` is the default property, so it is implicit when you don't specify it) :

```
Sub CopyPasteRawData()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rnewma\Documents\Excel Projects\Test\CPWholeDocTest1.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rnewma\Documents\Excel Projects\Test\CPWholeDocTest2.xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
DoEvents
'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:B5").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5").Value

'Close x:
'x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This still comes up as nothing but blanks on the book I am copying to.

Comment: Are they big workbooks? What is the data inside `x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")`?

Comment: I will link them for you, but as this is just a proof of concept I was doing, they are tiny.  The real thing is going to be fairly massive.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUxX8rRDJttZzVBaS1QM1U2ajQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUxX8rRDJtta1l0dGhaUTZhNDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Mkay... they seems good... Is the edition protected? Because they might have been open in read only or something like that! Try the edit, I deactivated the Read only on the destination workbook! ;)

Comment: Alex4336 solved it.  I need to replace the  "y = Workbooks.Open" portion with "y = ThisWorkbook" in combination with adding the ".Value" to the end of my copy/paste code.

Comment: @Rich : ok, I didn't get at first that you were "reopening" the workbook in which you launched the code!! Glad it is solved! Take a minute to take the tour and learn how to accept answers and use votes : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this to help others as there are a ton of other threads that weren't quite right but close enough to confuse me.  Hopefully this can help others in the future.

The Working Code:

```
Sub CopyPasteRawData2()

' CopyPasteRawData Macro
'
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("pathname of file you are copying from")
Set y = ThisWorkbook

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("sheet you are copying to").Range("A1:B5").Value = x.Sheets("sheet you are copying from").Range("A1:B5").Value

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```